# Direct assignment to the forward side of a many-to-many set is prohibited. Use students_that_completed.set() instead

Tags: python, django, postgresql, serialization, django-rest-framework

This error happens when i try to create a new "Assignment" /Model instance.
ofc this is works perfectly fine in django admin panel but when i do the same with **django rest framework browsable api** it doesnt work.

here is my "Assignment" serializer class (AssignmentSerializer):

```
class AssignmentSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
   title = serializers.CharField(max_length=50)
   body = serializers.CharField(max_length=1000)
   attachment = serializers.FileField(max_length=100)
   class_name = serializers.CharField(max_length=50)
   students_that_completed = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Student.objects.all(), many=True)
   owner = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Teacher.objects.all())


   def create(self, validated_data):
      """ 
      Create and return an "Assignment" instance.
      """
      print(validated_data)
      return Assignment.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't create an object AND something that is `many=True`. You need to handle that yourself.

Try something like this.

```
class AssignmentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    title = serializers.CharField(max_length=50)
    body = serializers.CharField(max_length=1000)
    attachment = serializers.FileField(max_length=100)
    class_name = serializers.CharField(max_length=50)
    students_that_completed = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Student.objects.all(), many=True)
    owner = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Teacher.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = Assignment
        fields = ['title', 'body', 'attachment', 'class_name', 'students_that_completed', 'owner']

    @transaction.atomic
    def create(self, validated_data):
        students = validated_data.pop('students_that_completed', [])

        obj = super().create(validated_data)

        if students:
            obj.students_that_completed.set(students)

        return obj
```

I don't know how your models look so you might need to adjust this line.

```
obj.students_that_completed.set(students)
```

Comment: tnx for you're time, this line is not working for me, what should i import to my project? @transaction.atomic

Comment: `from django.db import transaction`

Comment: got this error : ``create()` must be implemented.``

Comment: ah yes, you should be using `ModelSerializer`. You might need to adjust `fields`. Try now.

Comment: ye it works with ModelSerializer. but then i dont need all of those things like fields, create, update... i just need a Meta and it does the job

Comment: its like ModelSerializer is a shorter way to achive the goal but whats the difference

Comment: it maps better to models.  You only need to provide `fields` in Meta. Anything else is optional. If you remove `owner = ...` it will work as well because it knows `Assignment` has `owner` field which is a `Teacher` model.